# Replacing all outbound links to a certain domain in Wordpress

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, replace

I maintain a Wordpress site for a client of mine. They do all the content, I just keep it running and do the theme work.

A site they've linked to a few hundred times has changed domain and they've (very rudely) not redirected traffic from their old domain, so users clicking on an old link see a 404.

So we're left in the position where we need to fix all the links. The static ones (in theme files) have been easy enough to replace but, as I say, there are hundreds of these blighters littered all over the website in the posts.

Is there a quick method to find-and-replace links like this?

If there's not a Wordpress or PHP method, I'm happy to log in to the database over SSH and fire some SQL off manually... But what SQL do I want?

Answer (score 3):

Running a query is indeed the easiest and cleanest way.

1. **Back up the database** of course
2. According to [this blog post](http://www.onextrapixel.com/2010/01/30/13-useful-wordpress-sql-queries-you-wish-you-knew-earlier/) (I'm too lazy to look the columns up on a live WP but this looks about right), the right query is

   ```
   UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = 
                   REPLACE (post_content, 
                            'http://www.oldsiteurl.com', 
                            'http://www.newsiteurl.com');
   ```

Answer (score 3):

There also is a WordPress plugin for that: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search-and-replace/ I have used it when moving my own site and it worked nicely.